# Spring JDBC Template. How can get outcome variables of the pl/sql script

Tags: java, plsql, spring-jdbc

I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for run pl/sql script. 
But I don't know how can I get the values ​​of out variables (**:id_out**). 
Thanks in advance.

```
String script = "declare 
                   begin 
                     if myFunc(:id_in) is null then 
                        :id_out := 0; 
                     else 
                        :id_out := 1; 
                     end if; 
                   end;";
Map<String,Object> bindVars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
bindVars.put(id_in,1);
bindVars.put(id_out,2);


jdbcTmpl.execute(script, bindVars, new PreparedStatementCallback<Object>() {
    @Override public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement cs)
        throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        cs.execute();
        return null;
                }
       }
       );
```

Comment: What is it that you want? Your SQL is not a query (i.e doesn't return anything) and you do `return null` anyway so......?

Comment: I need to access the values ​​of variables (for example `id_out`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate (or any other subclass of JdbcTemplate) with anonymous PL/SQL blocks such as that above.  You'll have to wrap your anonymous PL/SQL block into a stored procedure or function.

Spring is intended to be portable across databases.  As far as I know, neither MySQL nor SQL Server have a concept analogous to Oracle's anonymous PL/SQL blocks (I'm happy to be proved wrong on this point, though).  Since this feature isn't portable across databases, Spring can't really support it for just Oracle.

Comment: SQL Server can execute "blocks" through JDBC. See [this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/23/sql-server-alter-table-set-default/) for an example block that [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) executes when emulating a `ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY col DEFAULT val` statement

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with a plain JdbcTemplate as in the following example, but note the way that the OUT value must be specified in the anonymous plsql block with "? := 'something';

java parameters used below: String id="12345" and String fixSql=

```
    declare
        p_id VARCHAR2(20) := null; 
        p_status_message VARCHAR2(32767) := null;
    begin
        p_id := ?;
        p_status_message := ' Everything is possible: ' || p_id;
        ? := 'Return text.' || p_status_message;
    end;
```

Note the two question marks above - the first is effectively an IN parameter and the second an OUT parameter. This code will call it:

```
    public class Foo extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    ...
    public String doAnonymousPlSql(final String id, String fixSql) throws CustomerFixException {
        String resultValue = getJdbcTemplate().execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement sql = connection.prepareCall(fixSql);
                sql.setString(1, id);
                sql.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
                return sql;
            }
        }
        , new CallableStatementCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement callablestatement) throws SQLException,
                    DataAccessException {
                callablestatement.executeUpdate();
                return (String) callablestatement.getObject(2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can also use named parameters in your CallableStatement - cstmt.registerOutParameter("id_out", Types.NUMERIC);

Comment: How to extract param of type "type id_list IS TABLE OF tablename1.id%type"  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SqlParameter> params = new LinkedList<SqlParameter>();
params.add(new SqlParameter(Types.NUMERIC));
params.add(new SqlParameter(Types.NUMERIC));
params.add(new SqlOutParameter("out_param_1", Types.NUMERIC));
params.add(new SqlOutParameter("out_param_2", Types.NUMERIC));
Map<String, Object> ret = simpleJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().call(
new CallableStatementCreator() {

    @Override
    public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("DECLARE ..." + 
                                               "BEGIN ... " + 
                                               "delete from table where table_field_1 = ? and table_field_2 = ? " + 
                                               "returning out_param_1, out_param_2 into ?, ?; " + 
                                               "END;"
        cs.setInt(1, first_in_param_value);
        cs.setInt(2, second_in_param_value);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.NUMERIC);
        return cs;
    }
}, params);

ret.get("out_param_1");
ret.get("out_param_1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Spring Data:

```java
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "DECLARE ... BEGIN ... (PL/SQL Block with named binding parameters) END;",
    new MapSqlParameterSource
        .addValue("parameter1", value1)
        .addValue("parameter2", value2));
```