# Passing Dynamic Parameters to a PL/SQL Anonymous Block with Spring's JdbcTemplate StoredProcedure

Tags: spring, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, jdbctemplate

I am using Oracle 11.2 with Spring 3.0.

I need to know whether it is possible to pass dynamic parameters to an anonymous block that some of these parameters are not going to be used by the target stored procedure if the implementation is of `JdbcTemplate StoredProcedure`. Here's the scenario:

I am able to to create an anonymous block to call a stored procedure with `JdbcTemplate's StoredProcedure`. The reason for the anonymous block is that the procedures take `IN` **known** `BOOLEAN` value (in the case below, `false`) which SQL does not support, but PL/SQL does, i.e.:

```
declare
  bool1_value boolean := false;
  bool2_value boolean := false;
begin

  stored_proc_call(param1 => :param1_value,
                  bool1 => bool1_value,
                  bool2 => bool2_value);
end;
```

I can pass `param1_value` through declaring and setting a parameter variable in the `StoredProcedure` class. However, I have run into procedures that require, say, `bool1` to be determined based on a result of another query, i.e.:

```
declare
  bool1_value boolean := false;
  bool2_value boolean := false;
begin

  for x in ( select count(*) rows
             from dual 
             where exists ( 
                select null
                from some_table s
                where s.id = :id
  ) )
  loop
      if ( x.rows = 1 ) 
      then
        bool1_value := true;
      else 
        bool1_value := false; -- don't worry about the redundancy here
      end if;
  end loop;

  stored_proc_call(param1 => :param1_value,
                  bool1 => bool1_value,
                  bool2 => bool2_value);
end;
```

As you can see, I want to know if there is a way to pass the value of `id` to the same anonymous block through `StoredProcedure` (without declaring it as a parameter to the stored procedure `stored_proc_call`.

The reason for this is to have everything in one anonymous block call, rather than having the select query split into a separate JdbcTemplate call, and based on the result, set `bool1` like `param1`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something.  Why wouldn't you simply pass the local variable `bool1_value` to `stored_proc_call` as the first parameter rather than using a separate bind variable?

Comment: @JustinCave I am, but its value needs to be set once the loop is executed. However, as I mentioned in the original post, parameter `id` needs to be fed to the aggregated query which is not part of the stored procedure call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JDBC Template. How can get outcome variables of the pl/sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247430/spring-jdbc-template-how-can-get-outcome-variables-of-the-pl-sql-script)