# How to lock a table to exclusive mode in spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

Noob spring question.  How do I run the below sql statement in spring.  So far I have only used the 'NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' class using a JDBC connection to a postgresql database.

```
begin;
lock table tx_test_queue in exclusive mode;
update tx_test_queue
set status='running'
where
    job_id in (
        select job_id
        from tx_test_queue
        where status='queued'
        order by job_id asc
        limit 1 )
returning job_id;
commit;
```

This is the Java code I'm using that is not working.

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( BatchQueueDAO.class );

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

public BatchQueueBean getNextBatchJob() {
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.append( "begin;" );
    sql.append( "lock table batch_queue in exclusive mode;" );
    sql.append( "update batch_queue set status_cd=2 where id in ( select id from batch_queue where status_cd=1 order by id asc limit 1) returning id;" );
    sql.append( "commit;" );

    SQLBuilderUtil.printMap( params, logger );

    List<BatchQueueBean> r = template.query( sql.toString(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>( BatchQueueBean.class ) );
    if( r.isEmpty() )
        return null;
    else
        return r.get( 0 );      
}
```

It is returning a *'Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query'* error.

Comment: Can't use NamedJdbTemplate to execute pl/sql see anwers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247430/spring-jdbc-template-how-can-get-outcome-variables-of-the-pl-sql-script

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Bummer it won't work.  Any idea how I would do this in spring?  I just need to lock the table so I can read and update a row without other threads picking up the same row.

Comment: In the link I shared, one of the answers shows how to use a callable statement - you can use that to execute a pl/sql block

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Query(value = "LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void lockTable();
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081097/2009145