# Spring data jpa insert into multiple tables to avoid locking tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Can you please help me understand how to insert entities into multiple tables efficiently?

I have 3 tables and 3 entities accordingly. Pricebook has an array of SKUs, and each SKU has 1 price. Basically what I want is to insert multiple entities transactionally, in case of constraint I must update entities in a chain.

[image]

The problem occurred once I try to insert into DB more than 1 Pricebook in parallel, so I'm actually catching a PostgreSQL deadlock. I found a workaround is to insert them one by one putting them in the queue but I understand that it's not a great idea.

This might be a stupid question and has been already answered before, but I hope someone could give me a hint.

```java
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "pricebook")
    public class Pricebook {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
       private Long id;
       //....
    }

    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "sku")
    public class Sku {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;
       //....
    }

    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "price")
    public class Price {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;

       @JoinColumn(name = "pricebook_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private Pricebook pricebook;

       @JoinColumn(name = "sku_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private Sku sku;

       //....
    }
```

Here is PricebookService logic of an upsert.

```
  @NonNull
    @Transactional
    public Pricebook createPricebook(@NonNull CreatePricebookRequest request) {
        final Instant startDate = PricebookConverter.toDate(request.getStartDate());
        final Instant expirationDate = PricebookConverter.toDate(request.getExpirationDate());

        if (startDate.isAfter(expirationDate)) {
            throw new InvalidParametersException("The pricebook's start date later then its expiration date.");
        }

        final Region region = regionService.findRegionByName(request.getRegion());

        final Optional<Pricebook> isPricebookFound =
                pricebookRepository.findByRegionAndPricebookTypeAndStartDateAndExpirationDate(region,
                        request.getPricebookName(), startDate, expirationDate);

        final Pricebook savedOrUpdatedPricebook;
        if (isPricebookFound.isPresent()) {
            final Pricebook foundPricebook = isPricebookFound.get();

            savedOrUpdatedPricebook = pricebookRepository.save(
                    new Pricebook(foundPricebook.getPricebookId(), request.getName(), foundPricebook.getPricebookName(), foundPricebook.getRegion(), foundPricebook.getStartDate(),
                            foundPricebook.getExpirationDate());

            logger.info("pricebook is updated successfully, pricebook={}", savedOrUpdatedPricebook);
        } else {
            savedOrUpdatedPricebook = pricebookRepository.save(
                    new Pricebook(request.getName(), request.getPricebookType(), region, startDate, expirationDate);

            logger.info("pricebook is created successfully, pricebook={}", savedOrUpdatedPricebook);
        }

        final List<Sku> skus = skuService.createSku(savedOrUpdatedPricebook, request.getSkus());
        logger.debug("skus are saved successfully, skus={}", skus);
        return savedOrUpdatedPricebook;
    }
```

Here is SkuService logic of an upsert. `skuToCreateOrUpdate` basically is just a method which wraps logic if it's found or new and return a new object.

```
    @NonNull
    public List<Sku> createSku(@NonNull Pricebook pricebook, @NonNull List<CreateSkuRequest> skus) {
        return skus.stream().map(sku -> {
            final Optional<Sku> foundSku = skuRepository.findByCode(sku.getCode());

            final Sku savedOrUpdatedSku = skuRepository.save(skuToCreateOrUpdate(sku, foundSku.map(Sku::getSkuId).orElse(null)));

            final List<Price> prices = priceService.createPrices(pricebook, savedOrUpdatedSku, sku.getPrice());
            logger.debug("prices are saved successfully, prices={}", prices);
            return savedOrUpdatedSku;
        }).collect(toList());
    }
```

Here is PriceService logic of an upsert.

```
    @NonNull
    public List<Price> createPrices(@NonNull Pricebook pricebook, @NonNull Sku sku, @NonNull CreatePriceRequest price) {
        final Optional<Price> foundPrice = priceRepository.findByPricebookAndSku(pricebook, sku);

        final Price savedOrUpdatedPrice;
        if (foundPrice.isPresent()) {
            final Price priceToUpdate = foundPrice.get();
            savedOrUpdatedPrice = priceRepository.save(
                    new Price(priceToUpdate.getPriceId(),
                            pricebook,
                            sku);
            logger.info("price is updated successfully, price={}", savedOrUpdatedPrice);
        } else {
            savedOrUpdatedPrice = priceRepository.save(
                    new Price(pricebook, sku);
            logger.info("price is created successfully, price={}", savedOrUpdatedPrice);
        }

        return Collections.singletonList(savedOrUpdatedPrice);
    }
```

I'm using a JpaRepository all over the places. Like so..

```
@Repository
public interface PricebookRepository extends JpaRepository<Pricebook, Long> {}

@Repository
public interface SkuRepository extends JpaRepository<Sku, Long> {}

@Repository
public interface PriceRepository extends JpaRepository<Price, Long> {}
```

Comment: Is there an error message telling you *why* you got the deadlock? The way I understand it, if you're running the same entity creation operation in both transactions, you shouldn't be getting a deadlock, because the order of insertion will be the same, so there's no circular wait. Please post the service method, and perhaps enable SQL logging, to see which statements become deadlocked

Comment: Yes, sure, the error message looks smth. like that below:

`ERROR: deadlock detected Detail: Process 27988 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1996705435; blocked by process 27990. Process 27990 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1996705089; blocked by process 27988. Hint: See server log for query details. Where: while inserting index tuple (153,8) in relation "sku"; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected`

Comment: Could you also please post the code you're using to insert the `Pricebook`? You mentioned sth about upserting and constraints, so I imagine there is some conditional logic? I also understand `sku` is more like a lookup table, do the entities in the two transactions share any `sku`s? Also, it would help to see the actual queries each transaction executes, because then we can deduce what locks are being acquired

Comment: You can try to resolve the problem by acquiring locks in the `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` mode upfront (as the first query in your code) for any entities your service method will potentially update. However, we cannot help any further without seeing the code and/or queries

Comment: @crizzis Sure, thank you. I've added 3 methods, from 3 services.
Pricebook is calling SkuService.createSkus() for each sku code to save or update, and inside it is calling PriceService.createPrice() to create price, accordingly.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what happens after the `if (foundPrice.isPresent()) {` line. If `priceRepository.findByPricebookAndSku(pricebook, sku)` returns a non-empty result, that means it already has the correct `price` and `sku`, so why do you still need the `priceRepository.save(new Price(...))` part? Why not just `return Collections.singletonList(foundPrice.get())` at that point? Same question for `Sku`s

Comment: In any case, see my answer

Comment: @crizzis, Basically I keep this logic cause if pricebook or sku has been found, I need to update fields of sku or pricebook. 
Sorry this object new Pricebook(...) might realy confuse, cause there is nothing to update, but in project, there are a lots of fields, which I don't actually put here, just to avoid to much lines of code and to focus only on the logic, but just pretend, there are some fields which I may receive from user request

Comment: Well, in that case you could simply update the retrieved object (`foundPrice.setSku()` etc.) but - fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might be facing [this issue](https://rcoh.svbtle.com/postgres-unique-constraints-can-cause-deadlock), which is pretty likely especially if both transactions attempt to insert the same SKUs.

If that's the case, I can think of two ways to mitigate it:

1. **Partial solution**: try sorting the SKUs in `List<CreateSkuRequest> skus` by `sku.code` and (if that's not enough) using `saveAndFlush()` to store them, ensuring the order of insertion. This should eliminate the circular wait, meaning that now, at least one of the transactions should succeed (the other will probably get a unique constraint violation)
2. **Full solution**: if you prefer both transactions to succeed, you would have to acquire a table-level lock for the `SKU` table. You should be able to do this using a custom update query:

```
@Query(value = "LOCK TABLE SKU IN EXCLUSIVE MODE", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void lockTable();
```

then, just call the method as the first operation inside `createSku`. Note that this might turn out to be only marginally more efficient than putting the transactions in a queue, so if I were you, I'd probably still just go with that approach.

EDIT I also didn't quite understand the exact scenario which gives you the consistent result of two transactions clashing, is this a batch insert type of thing that you're trying to parallelize? If you're *really* bent on running the transactions in parallel, perhaps you could group your input set so that the SKUs don't overlap. Or, deduplicate and insert the `Sku`s upfront. As I said, I don't know what the use case is, so not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution and get back with result

Comment: Seems like you're right, locking is more efficient rather than do that in a queue. Thank you, that helped me

Comment: If one of the transaction fails (due to some sort of the exception), do you manually need to release the lock or it is done automatically somehow? How does this part work?

Comment: Locking only makes sense in the context of a transaction. Once the transaction is rolled back for whatever reason, the locks are obviously released